# `ngResource` - config issue to get array of data from server

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am using `deployd` as my server here. When I type `http://localhost:5500/products` - it produce me the result as like this:

```
[{"name":"Apples","category":"Fruit","price":1.2,"id":"1bc7e360530b28fb"},{"name":"Bananas","category":"Fruit","price":2.42,"id":"9c5d8a618181486e"},{"name":"Pears","category":"Fruit","price":2.02,"id":"7c744dfc08ce085b"},{"name":"Tuna","category":"Fish","price":20.45,"id":"d00c7dbc1f0ab937"},{"name":"Salmon","category":"Fish","price":17.93,"id":"80bb9da35d120b0a"},{"name":"Trout","category":"Fish","price":12.93,"id":"81b199043e64681e"}]
```

but when I use the `ngResource` I am getting error as :

> GET http://localhost:5500/products/:id 404 (Not Found)

I am not getting any data. here is my config in `ngResource` module.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
angular.module("promiseApp", ["updatePrice", "ngResource"])
.constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products/")
.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, baseUrl) {

    $scope.displayMode = "list";
    $scope.currentProduct = null;

    $scope.productsResource = $resource(baseUrl+"/products/:id", {id: "@id"}, {create: {method: "POST"}, save: {method: "PUT"}, update: {method: "PUT"}});

    $scope.listProducts = function () {
        $scope.products = $scope.productsResource.query();
    }

    $scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
        product.$delete().then(function () {
            $scope.products.splice($scope.products.indexOf(product), 1);
        });
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }

    $scope.createProduct = function (product) {
        new $scope.productsResource(product).$create().then(function (newProduct) {
            $scope.products.push(newProduct);
            $scope.displayMode = "list";
        });
    }

    $scope.updateProduct = function (product) {
        product.$save();
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }

    $scope.editOrCreateProduct = function (product) {
        $scope.currentProduct = product ? product : {};
        $scope.displayMode = "edit";
    }

    $scope.saveEdit = function (product) {
        if (angular.isDefined(product.id)) {
            $scope.updateProduct(product);
        } else {
            $scope.createProduct(product);
        }
    }

    $scope.cancelEdit = function () {
        if ($scope.currentProduct && $scope.createProduct.$get) {
            $scope.currentProduct.$get();
        }
        $scope.currentProduct = {};
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }

    $scope.listProducts();
});
```

Where is wrong here in my code? any one correct me to producing correct config please? I am looking for all my `CURD` process need to work fine.

Comment: Look at the Network tab in Developer Tools / Firebug. Is Angular even making a request? (I would assume so because you say it 404s) If so, what is the *actual* URL being requested by Angular?

Comment: @karwilbur, I guess, from my param config ` $resource(baseUrl + ":id",` this part goes for request. in the console i am getting like this `http://localhost:5500/products/:id`, response as : `http://localhost:5500/products/:id`

Comment: I strongly believe that my `ngResource` config is wrong here `$scope.productsResource =`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Angular is taking the `:id` part as a literal part of the URL rather than a placeholder. I've never done it that way, so I can be certain what Angular is thinking there.

Answer (score 0):

I usually define my controllers a little differently. Something like:

```
.controller('thingController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){
  Thing = $resource("/things/:id", {id: "@id"}, {create: {method: "POST"}, save: {method: "PUT"}, update: {method: "PUT"}});
  $scope.things = Thing.query();
}]);
```

EDIT:
So, Try just this and see what happens:

```
angular.module("promiseApp", ["updatePrice", "ngResource"])
.controller('productController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){
  Product = $resource("/products/:id", {id: "@id"}, {create: {method: "POST"}, save: {method: "PUT"}, update: {method: "PUT"}});
  $scope.products = Product.query();
  $scope.updateProduct: function(product){ 
    return $resource('/products/:id', {id: '@id'}, {'update': {method: "PUT"}}).update(product); 
  };
}]);
```

Comment: there is noting new in your answer adding the `update` method. even i tried, nothing works.

Comment: I added a `/` in front of `id` it works: `$scope.productsResource = $resource(baseUrl+"/:id", { id: "@id" },` - but `put` method is not working. can  you guess what is the wrong here?

Comment: That's what I said, it works find for listing the object. but i can't able to `edit` or `update`. I am getting the error as :  while edit `POST http://localhost:5500/products//products/:id 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Try my second example and add an update method in there: `$scope.updateProduct: function(product){
      return $resource('/products/:id', {id: '@id'}, {'update': {method: "PUT"}}).update(product);
    }`

Comment: I am thrown by error "`ReferenceError: product is not defined' I updated the code there in my question. can you directly udpate there in this?

Comment: you miss an 's' , it should be 'products'?

Comment: @huanfeng,  where at update method?  `    $scope.productsResource = $resource(baseUrl+"/products/:id", {id: "@id"}, {create: {method: "POST"}, save: {method: "PUT"}, update: {method: "PUT"}}).update(products);
` - still getting error.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Remove `baseUrl+` from `baseUrl+"/products/:id"`. That is causing the URL to look like `/products//products/:id` when it should be `/products/:id`.

Comment: If i remove that, `$scope.products = $scope.productsResource.query();` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we define a entity-factory in a separate file like:

entity-factory.js:

```
angular.module('promiseApp') //update
.factory('ProductsEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/products/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
            create: {method: 'POST'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
}]);
```

in you controller.js:

```
angular.module('promiseApp').controller('AnotherModuleCtrl', ['$scope',...,'ProductsEntity', function(){
    //here we do update by id
    ProductsEntity.update({id: productId}, newProduct, function (res) {
        ...
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Apart from seperating a new module there is nothing new here. But let me try the way as you suggest and get back to you.

Comment: No I coun'd find a solution here.

Comment: could you paste your code to a plnkr, so i can see where the issue is

Comment: sure. now my `productsEntity.js` file has the following: `angular.module('productsEntity')
.factory('ProductsEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'http://localhost:5500/products/products/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
            create: {method: 'POST'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
}]);`

Comment: My product.js contains the `productsEntity` like this : `angular.module("promiseApp", ["updatePrice", "ngResource","productsEntity"])
// .constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products/")
.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, productsEntity) {

    $scope.displayMode = "list";
    $scope.currentProduct = null;

    $scope.listProducts = function () {
        $scope.products = productsEntity.query(); //getting query
    }`

Comment: in productEntity.js change  angular.module('productsEntity')
.factory('ProductsEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {            to        angular.module('promiseApp')
.factory('ProductsEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {                        i have updated it in my answer

Comment: I confused here. can i put my project as zip file to you? can i you initiate a chat?

Answer (score 0):

Appologies, the mistake is mine. instead of `angular-resource` i installed the `ng-resource` using bower. that cause all the issues. fixed that my friends!